# Managing TabBar Actions when changing TabBar dynamically

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am wondering how I can Manage tabs as they are changing dynamically.

For Example. On my Home screen I have 4 tabs. When I click the 2nd tab. I will now have 5 different tabs. I know how to add them dynamically but I am having troubles managing what happens when they are clicked.

For example Home screen is my first tab.

```
if (viewController == [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]){
```

That will handle my actions for the first tab but when I change my tabs when I click the second tab I don't want my first tab to be the the first home page from my first set of tabs. Is there a way to manage tabbar click by identity and not by index number? Another example is my logout function is tabbar 4 in the first set and tab 5 in the second set. I dont want the the 4th tab in the second set to logout and currently it does cause it reads the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike, it seems to me that you are asking too  much for an UITabBar. How ever, I've been in your situation where a client wants a dynamic tab bar. Delegation is you best friend in this case.

UITabBarDelegate:

```
– tabBar:willBeginCustomizingItems:
– tabBar:didBeginCustomizingItems:
– tabBar:willEndCustomizingItems:changed:
– tabBar:didEndCustomizingItems:changed:
– tabBar:didSelectItem:  required method
```

UITabBarControllerDelgate

```
Managing Tab Bar Selections
– tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:
– tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
Managing Tab Bar Customizations
– tabBarController:willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:
– tabBarController:willEndCustomizingViewControllers:changed:
– tabBarController:didEndCustomizingViewControllers:changed:
```

this will let you manage the actions that will be done when something is up on the tab bar.

Also you can actually change the icon on a tab bar without removing it by changing the tab bar item on the view controller

```
UIViewController * controller =     [myTabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:kObjectIndex];

UIImage *someImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some_icon_on.png"];

UITabBarItem *someTabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString (@"SomeTabBarTitle",@"") image:someImage tag:kObjectIndex];


controller.tabBarItem = someTabBarItem;
```

I hope this helps you. Best of luck!

Comment: Your solution worked.  However, myTabBarController.tabBar.items should be myTabBarController.viewControllers instead.

Comment: the solution has a few years now so it's possible that the API changed. thanks for pointing it out!